Social networking app: comments being replaced by each other
I am creating a social networking app using android studio and java.
My problem is in comments functionality in the comments section of the app. Whenever a user tries to post a comment, his previous comments are replaced by new ones.
Here's the code where i think is the problem. I've added the push() method as well at the end of PostsRef database reference, but still comments are replacing each other.
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_comments);

    Post_key = getIntent().getExtras().get("PostKey").toString();
    PostsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts").child(Post_key).child("comments").push();
    String comment_push_id = PostsRef.getKey();

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    current_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

    CommentsList = findViewById(R.id.comments_list);
    CommentsList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    CommentsList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

Here's the related part of code which might be useful -
PostCommentButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        UsersRef.child(current_user_id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if(snapshot.exists())
                {
                    String userName = snapshot.child("username").getValue().toString();
                    ValidateComment(userName);

                    CommentInputText.setText("");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });
    }
});

Here's the part of code where a user inserts the comments into the firebase database -
private void ValidateComment(String userName) {
    String commentText = CommentInputText.getText().toString();

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(commentText))
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please write text to comment...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
    {
        Calendar callForDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yyyy");
        final String saveCurrentDate = currentDate.format(callForDate.getTime());

        Calendar callForTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        final String saveCurrentTime = currentTime.format(callForDate.getTime());

        final String RandomKey = current_user_id + saveCurrentDate + saveCurrentTime;

        HashMap commentsMap = new HashMap();
        commentsMap.put("uid",current_user_id);
        commentsMap.put("comment",commentText);
        commentsMap.put("date",saveCurrentDate);
        commentsMap.put("time",saveCurrentTime);
        commentsMap.put("username",userName);
       PostsRef.child(RandomKey).updateChildren(commentsMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
           @Override
           public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
               if(task.isSuccessful())
               {
                   Toast.makeText(CommentsActivity.this,"comment posted successfully....",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
               else
               {
                   Toast.makeText(CommentsActivity.this,"Error Occured, Try Again...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
           }
       });
    }
}

In the database also some comments are not getting stored, while only the replaced ones are getting stored.

Going forward please don't delete-and-repost when we request a change. There's an edit link right under your post to make the requested changes, which allows us to keep the full context.

Ok Sir I’ll keep that in mind, but please help

Did you try to debug it or add a log? Try to focus more on reproducing the issue and where it happens.

No sir, I’m a beginner, I can’t figure out what’s the main cause of problem is

I've resolved this issue by calling the .setValue() method agter i get the key using getKey();
PostsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts").child(Post_key).child("comments").push();
String comment_push_id = PostsRef.getKey();
PostsRef.setValue(comment_push_id);
